# Use the output of system2 as a file input for an R function that expects file

Tags: r

How to use the output of running a system command via system2 in R as an input for an R function without writing the output to a file?

So instead of having to write to a temporary file like this:

```
system2('ls', args = c('-la'), stdout = 'file.tmp')
read.table(file = 'file.tmp')
```

I want to skip writing the file. Something like this:

```
read.table(file = system2('ls', args = c('-la')) )
```

Comment: you can skip writing to a file if `stdout = TRUE` which returns the output

Comment: @rawr Thanks, but I need to have the output to be parsed by the second R function, which expects a file or a connection.

Comment: are you speaking in general or for `read.table`?  `read.table(text = system2(..., stdout = TRUE))` would work and there is also `?textConnection`

Comment: I am speaking in general. The function I want is from the ape package, read.FASTA, which expects a file or a connection in fasta format. I am trying to fiddle with textConnection(), but can't get it to work yet.